# Power Bi - Switch and Group By

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have column that has 2 text options - "Public Finance" and "Corporate Finance". I would like to create a filter, but I would like to have a 3 combine/group option - "Sector Finance". I already tried with Switch and Group By, but its not working. Hope anyone has an idea how I can do it?
Expected result:

Type:
Sector Finance (Public Finance+Corporate Finance),
Public Finance,
Corporate Finance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use this approach:

First create a new table using [New Table] on the Modeling-tab. Like this:

[image]

I used this for a small table with sample data:

[image]

Then create a one direction, many to many relationship: `tblFilter[Column Value] -----> tblData[Type]`:

[image]

A slicer using tblFilter[Filter Value], that filters a matrix visual would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look at the hierarchySlicer you can download in the marketplace.
This way you can choose either one, but you can also choose both. The way this works is you can choose your sector, so you would select both, or you can choose your sector and then specify your category.

You would have to make two columns, one with Sector finance for all rows and one column with your categories (i.e. Public and Corporate).

If you would have more sectors you can use the hierarchy slicer to choose between sectors and then for each sector choose between "categories".

Hope this helps